# Can concurrently inserted records overlap in the table?

Tags: sql-server

Let's say we have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable (SomeKey int IDENTITY(1,1), SomeInt int)
```

And we have two insert statements that were executed simultaneously:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable (SomeInt) 
SELECT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 1

INSERT INTO SomeTable (SomeInt)
SELECT 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 2
```

Is there a scenario where in the end of all this, the table would look like this?
[image]

Comment: As I read your question, it seems to me that you make an assumption that is not valid. Rows in a table have no order by definition. The only way you can "look" at a table is to query it and rows within a resultset also have no particular order if the query that generated it has no order by clause. The database engine is free to return those rows in any manner - despite what pattern you might see using a system that has little resource contention.

Comment: Well, I am not asking about the order of the records in the table itself. I wanted to know if there was a possibility that the records inserted by two insert statements would overlap. Hence the example of the 1s being inserted simultaneously with the 2s and with both of them not having consecutive identities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15):

> The identity property on a column **does not** guarantee the following:
>
> - Consecutive values within a transaction - A transaction inserting multiple rows is not guaranteed to get consecutive values for the rows because other concurrent inserts might occur on the table. If values must be consecutive then the transaction should use an exclusive lock on the table or use the SERIALIZABLE isolation level.

Emphasis mine.

Although unlikely, yes, it could happen if both transactions occurred at the exact same time.